# Blender game engine Armature mouse control

Tags: rendering, game-engine, rigging, armature

I am creating an online shooting game. How do i control my armature arm with mouse like other online games? So the gun will always shoot to the middle of the target. Previously, I successfully done that by seperating the arms and the arms armature and use game logic to set mouse actuator on it.But i just changed my rig to improve the movement . I tried the same method but it didn't work. Here is the file. http://www.mediafire.com/download/rpvgidxbadd517s/Sample.blend
Really hope you can help me with it. Been struggling with this for the whole day.